# How to apply the 'maven:' prefix in a ceylon module descriptor

Tags: maven, ceylon

My module descriptor looks like that:

```
native("jvm")module mod "1.0.0" {
    import "joda-time:joda-time" "2.9.4";
}
```

I can successfully compile and fat-jar it with ceylon 1.2.3.

But the compiler warns about prefixing it with 'maven:'.

```
source/mod1/module.ceylon:4: warning: use of old style Maven imports is deprecated, prefix with 'maven:'
    import "joda-time:joda-time" "2.9.4";
           ^
1 warning
```

Regardless of what position of the prefix I try (e.g. "maven:joda-time:joda-time", ...), it is not accepted.

Will using dependencies from maven central repository be supported by ceylon in the future or is this warning an announcment of a hard time in the future for those how want to resolve dependencies from maven central?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new, Ceylon 1.2.3 syntax is:

```
import maven:"joda-time:joda-time" "2.9.4";
```

That is, you put the namespace outside/before the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

> Will using dependencies from maven central repository be supported by ceylon in the future or is this warning an announcment of a hard time in the future for those how want to resolve dependencies from maven central?

No, it's an "announcement" of other types of repositories to come besides Maven. So Maven only lost it unique place as the only other type of repository supported besides Ceylon's own.

The old syntax will keep working as well, just with the nag message that you should really use the prefix.